# How connect to WildFly 10.1.0.Final ActiveMQ Artemis using JNDI and Spring?

Tags: spring, jms, jndi, spring-jms, wildfly-10

I have WildFly 10.1.0.Final, this have Artemis 1.1.0
Whats the correct way of configure jndi.properties?:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=false
```

This worket with WildFly 9.0.0.Final that have HornetQ:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=false
```

I'm using Spring 4.3.2, Spring-jms and included the wildfly-jms-client-bom in may Maven POM.xml.
The Next is my connection Factory.  Whith Wildfly 9 I try InitialContext.doLookup(..) and this work. But with WildFly 10 this don't work in same way.

My principal configuration files is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org")
@Import({
    MessagingConfiguration.class,
    MessagingListenerConfiguration.class

    })
public class AppConfig {

    //Put Other Application configuration here.


}
```

.

```
package org.jms.configuration;
@Configuration
public class MessagingConfiguration {

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException{

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
    return connectionFactory;
}

/*
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws NamingException {
    JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
    template.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    //template.setDefaultDestinationName(ORDER_RESPONSE_QUEUE);
    return template;
}
*/

}
```

And I have the next:

```
package org.jms.configuration;
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class MessagingListenerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;


    public MessagingListenerConfiguration() {
        System.out.println("MessagingListenerConfiguration::Constructor!!");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {

        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

        factory.setConcurrency("1-1");

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Finally I have this listener.

```
package org.jms.messaging;

import javax.jms.JMSException;

import org.gasmart.jms.model.Product;
import org.gasmart.jms.service.OrderService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MessageReceiver {

    //private static final String ORDER_QUEUE = "order-queue";

    /*
    *   <jms-queue name="shatTopic" entries="java:/jms/queue/shat java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/shat"/>
    */
    private static final String ORDER_QUEUE = "shat";

    public MessageReceiver() {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> OK");
    }

    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;


    @JmsListener(destination = ORDER_QUEUE)
    public void receiveMessage(final Message<String> message) {

        MessageHeaders headers =  message.getHeaders();

        System.out.println("MessageReceiver::receiveMessage(product)   Application : headers received : "+headers);

        //orderService.processOrder(product);


    }

}
```

I get this error:

20:04:42,971 WARN  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-124) Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'shat' - trying to recover. **Cause: There is no queue with name shat**

20:04:42,971 INFO  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-124) Successfully refreshed JMS Connection

The **shat** queue es declared in MessageReceiver class.
My standalone-full.xml is the next:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <security-setting name="jms.topic.chat">
                    <role name="guest2" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <remote-acceptor name="websocket-stomp" socket-binding="netty-ws"/>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <jms-queue name="shatTopic" entries="java:/jms/queue/shat java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/shat"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

I have defined the queue, that is correctly defined:

References about how declare a queue can consult here:  http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-jms/jboss-jms-configuration

Why I cant connect?? I don't understand. I actually tryied many many ways, don't work.

**UPDATE:  2016-August-29 - 10:00 A.M**

I found that if I restart all the wildfly with the application actually deployed, after load the application, If I connect a client (I have a Web client that produce messages directly to the "jms.queue.shat" queue using Websocket over STOMP with stomp.js) and send messages, the application (java) consume correctly the messages.  But if I redeploy the application after it was correctly working, this beging to produce ERROR.
The errors is next:

```
10:43:51,607 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool - 113) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /ServerApp
10:43:51,632 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "ServApp.war" (runtime-name : "ServApp.war")
10:43:56,588 INFO  [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2) JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection
10:43:56,592 ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2) Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'shat' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)
10:44:01,592 ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2) Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'shat' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=1, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)
10:44:06,593 ERROR [org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer] (DefaultMessageListenerContainer-2) Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'shat' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=2, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)
```

.....

The error say: **JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection** Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'shat'... Server locator is closed (maybe it was garbage collected)

Could be a Bug of ActiveMQ Artemis artemis 1.1.0.wildfly-017 ?

Some has resolved some similar?

**UPDATE:  2016-August-29 - 14:00 P.M.**

If someone is interested... I found that if you use JndiObjectFactoryBean to  looks up a JNDI object, in this case the JMS connection factory, the before problem goes away. Normally I found some examples using JndiObjectFactoryBean but for get Database data sources, almost no example to obtain a JMS connection factory.

Changing MessagingConfiguration class:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException{

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException{
    return ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = InitialContext.doLookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
}
```

with:

```
 @Bean
public JndiObjectFactoryBean solicitudesConnectionFactory() {
    JndiObjectFactoryBean jndi = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
    jndi.setJndiName("java:/ConnectionFactory");
    jndi.setLookupOnStartup(true);
    jndi.setProxyInterface(ConnectionFactory.class);
    return jndi;
}

public ConnectionFactory notificacionesConnectionFactory() {
    return  new  SingleConnectionFactory((ConnectionFactory)solicitudesConnectionFactory().getObject());
}
```

the connection to Artemis work correctly too, incluse if I do redeploy of the aplication.  But the jndi.properties file is not used more, and the "Server locator is closed" problem disappears.

I don't know if the JndiObjectFactoryBean if correct, but I will want continue using the jndi.properties file. How do it??

Comment: Maybe you need a  `DestinationResolver`?

Comment: I do not understand how. Now I just want to consume messages from a queue. Then I will implement the part for sending response messages.

Comment: Check this example, don't use:

http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-jms-activemq-example-with-jmslistener-enablejms/

Comment: You saved my life.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `ORDER_QUEUE` from `shat` to `java:/jms/queue/shat`